# Coming to America sparring scene; stunt men, or self-performed?

Tags: stunts, coming-to-america

In the beginning of *Coming to America*, there is a scene where Eddie Murphy's and Arsenio Hall's characters engage in a sparring session with I think they would be bo staffs.

Did they perform the sparring themselves, or did they have stuntmen doing that scene?

The scene which I am referring to can be seen on YouTube:

Comment: That's most certainly not Eddie Murphy doing backflips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed it was Lindell Blake who was Eddie Murphy's stunt double. Lindell's brother was my gymnastics coach and Lindell would join us every so often.

I happened to see his name in the closing credits of *Coming to America* years ago and I asked him about it. He confirmed that he was the stunt double, and that the final aerial skill of the pass he did (the laid out full) was done on a trampoline and cut into the scene to look like it was done off the floor.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=tecCAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=eddie%20murphy%20gymnastics%20stunts&source=bl&ots=KcbuNcHEKO&sig=pvNopbj-ebsLsgYzqEFrmwfNQ4k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yeHzU_O1JofesAT_pYD4Dw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=eddie%20murphy%20gymnastics%20stunts&f=false) from an article in *New York Magazine* (Page 51; Sep 18, 1989) a gymnast by the name of Lindell Blake was the stunt double for Eddie Murphy in that movie. He is also listed in [IMDB’s](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094898/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) list of stunt persons.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a screen cap to back this up or even the names of the dancers/gymnast/stuntment that were used but the flips are done by professionals. They are working as body doubles for Eddie Murphy and Arsenio Hall.

Comment: Please provide a source for your answer, otherwise it's simply, "Taking you at your word."

Comment: @MattD It's not exactly "taking you at your word" (which I've never really seen anybody have a problem with unless they are asking for proof or sources which this person didn't) if you watch the video it's fairly evident that an actual gymnast was used for the 10 backflips in a row and since Eddie Murphy doesn't have a professional gymnastic background it's more of a statement of logic. Unfortunately stunt doubles aren't normally noted for their work. Besides if Eddie Murphy could do that you'd hear about it in every movie interview he's ever done. It's classic "movie magic"